# htaccess RewriteRule keeps query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a RewriteRule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^thesection$ /sections.php [L]
RewriteRule ^thesection/(.*)$ /sections.php?show=$1 [L]
```

so, if I enter `domain.com/thesection` -> it works perfect

but!, if I enter `domain.com/thesection/hello` it redirects to `domain.com/thesection?show=hello`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I've spent hours googling. Please help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `domain.com/thesection/hello` supposed to get rewritten to?

Comment: Hi Jon, domain.com/thesection/hello should be interpreted by the server as domain.com/sections.php?show=hello
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this and let me know

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^thesection/?$ /sections.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^thesection/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/?$ /sections.php?show=$1 [L,QSA]
```

this will redirect `domain.com/thesection/hello` to `sections.php?show=hello`

the QSA flag means:

> This flag forces the rewrite engine to append a query string part of
>   the substitution string to the existing string, instead of replacing
>   it. Use this when you want to add more data to the query string via a
>   rewrite rule.

so you can add more parameters eg: `http://www.domain.com/thesection/hello/?page=1` this will output:

```
Array (
 [show] => hello
 [page] => 1
)
```

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong but that didn't help.
If I enter domain.com/thesection/hello, my browser redirects to domain.com/thesection?show=hello which is not the prettiest url ever seen. :( Thanks anyway, I've learned alot today.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I had a configuration mistake. This worked perfectly, thanks!